Safe upgrade to TLS 1.3 on centos/linux (save all configuration apache files)
I updated openssl and after command openssl version output is:
OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021
Download and install:
wget https://ftp.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz
tar -xzvf openssl-1.1.1k.tar.gz

cd openssl-1.1.1k

./config --prefix=/usr --openssldir=/etc/ssl --libdir=lib no-shared zlib-dynamic
make


I also run next commands:
yum -y update
yum install -y make gcc perl-core pcre-devel wget zlib-devel

ENV:
Content for FILE openssl.sh:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib64



ADD INTRO FOLDER :  /etc/profile.d/ FILE openssl.sh

I found that "- Apache versions 2.4.36 and later include TLS 1.3 support."
After command httpd -v output is:
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)

Look like i need to upgrade httpd service.
But with this command :
rpm -q --changelog httpd

Output:
* Thu Apr 27 2023 Luboš Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-99.1
- Resolves: #2190143 - mod_rewrite regression with CVE-2023-25690

* Tue Mar 21 2023 Luboš Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-97.7
- Resolves: #2177742 - CVE-2023-25690 httpd: HTTP request splitting with
  mod_rewrite and mod_proxy

* Wed Dec 07 2022 Luboš Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-97.6
- Resolves: #2101997 - HEAD request with a 404 and custom ErrorPage causes
  corrupt and mixed-up responses

* Tue Mar 22 2022 Luboš Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-97.5
- Resolves: #2065243 - CVE-2022-22720 httpd: HTTP request smuggling
  vulnerability in Apache HTTP Server 2.4.52 and earlier

* Mon Jan 10 2022 Luboš Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-97.4
- Resolves: #2031072 - CVE-2021-34798 httpd: NULL pointer dereference via
  malformed requests
- Resolves: #2031074 - CVE-2021-39275 httpd: out-of-bounds write in
  ap_escape_quotes() via malicious input
- Resolves: #1969226 - CVE-2021-26691 httpd: Heap overflow in mod_session

* Mon Jan 10 2022 Luboš Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-97.3
- Resolves: #2035058 - CVE-2021-44790 httpd: mod_lua: possible buffer overflow
  when parsing multipart content

* Mon Oct 25 2021 Luboš Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-97.2
- Resolves: #2015694 - proxy rewrite to unix socket fails with CVE-2021-40438 fix

* Thu Oct 07 2021 Luboš Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-97.1
- Resolves: #2011729 - CVE-2021-40438 httpd: mod_proxy: SSRF via a crafted
  request uri-path containing "unix:"

* Wed Oct 07 2020 Lubos Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-97
- Resolves: #1852350 - httpd/mod_proxy_http/mod_ssl aborted when sending
  a client cert to backend server
- Resolves: #1785100 - mod_cgid takes CGIDScriptTimeout x 2 seconds for timeout
- Resolves: #1862499 - Intermittent Segfault in Apache httpd due to pool
  concurrency issues

* Fri Apr 17 2020 Lubos Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-95
- Resolves: #1823262 - CVE-2020-1934 httpd: mod_proxy_ftp use of uninitialized
  value

* Thu Mar 26 2020 Lubos Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-94
- Resolves: #1565491 - CVE-2017-15715 httpd: <FilesMatch> bypass with a trailing
  newline in the file name
- Resolves: #1747283 - CVE-2019-10098 httpd: mod_rewrite potential open redirect
- Resolves: #1724879 - httpd terminates all SSL connections using an abortive
  shutdown
- Resolves: #1715981 - Backport of SessionExpiryUpdateInterval directive
- Resolves: #1565457 - CVE-2018-1303 httpd: Out of bounds read in
  mod_cache_socache can allow a remote attacker to cause a denial of service
- Resolves: #1566531 - CVE-2018-1283 httpd: Improper handling of headers in
  mod_session can allow a remote user to modify session data for CGI applications

* Tue Oct 08 2019 Lubos Uhliarik <luhliari@redhat.com> - 2.4.6-93
- Resolves: #1677496 - CVE-2018-17199 httpd: mod_session_cookie does not respect
  expiry time
 
 ....


Did my apache supports TLS1.3 or not ?
This is illegal also in config vhost [look like no support] :
SSLProtocol -all +TLSv1.3

About my linux :
    Virtualization: kvm
  Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
       CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
            Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-957.10.1.el7.x86_64
      Architecture: x86-64

Any suggestion ?

If you've downloaded, compiled, and installed OpenSSL 1.1.1k into /usr you've pretty much completely broken your OS installation.  Centos 7 utilities that use OpenSSL use OpenSSL 1.0.2, and that is not compatible with OpenSSL 1.1.1.  But you've overwritten the OS-installed OpenSSL binaries with incompatible versions.  You could have just installed the openssl11 set of packages...

Don't do this.
OpenSSL is used a lot of places. If you want to upgrade it, you have to recompile all the stuff that uses it - including Apache. At that point you don't run CentOS 7 anymore; you've compiled a lot yourself. Everytime a new vulnerability in any of the pieces you've compiled yourself is discovered, you have to start over again.
This ensures that you end up with an unmaintainable mess!
That is one of the things distributions offer: a combination of software that is tested and works together. In the case of CentOS and other LTS distros - they offer stable versions. You don't get new features, but you also don't get new libraries, so you don't have to recompile your shiny in-house proprietary app very often.
In addition CentOS 7 is nearing EOL (30. June 2024). Thus it makes no sense to spend energy on fixing stuff on that platform; spend the energy on finding a viable upgrade path to more modern software.
